# Uniswap V2 flashswap how to work with it?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv2

Problem: I need to make an arbitrage between two uniswap v2 like exchanges. I have researched many open-sourced repositories and read documentation, but still don't understand the next:

How to implement arbitrage logic inside `uniswapV2Call` callback function if I borrow token A then change it on side exchange and get token B, in result I need to return to protocol borrowed A token with protocol fee but I don't know where I can take it.
What could you suggest to do?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity =0.7.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import '@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol';
import '@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol';
import '@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Callee.sol';
import '@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol';


// flash swap contract
contract FlashswapDemo is IUniswapV2Callee {
    address private immutable WETH;
    address private immutable UniswapV2Factory;

    event LogAddress(string, address);
    event Log(string, uint256);

    constructor(address _uniV2Factory, address _weth) {
        UniswapV2Factory = _uniV2Factory;
        WETH = _weth;
    }

    // we'll call this function to call to call FLASHLOAN on uniswap
    function testFlashSwap(address _tokenBorrow, uint256 _amount, IUniswapV2Router02 _router) external {
        // check the pair contract for token borrow and weth exists
        address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(UniswapV2Factory).getPair(
            _tokenBorrow,
            WETH
        );
        require(pair != address(0), "!pair");

        // right now we dont know tokenborrow belongs to which token
        address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).token0();
        address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).token1();

        // as a result, either amount0out will be equal to 0 or amount1out will be
        uint256 amount0Out = _tokenBorrow == token0 ? _amount : 0;
        uint256 amount1Out = _tokenBorrow == token1 ? _amount : 0;

        // need to pass some data to trigger uniswapv2call
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(_tokenBorrow, _amount, _router);
        // last parameter tells whether its a normal swap or a flash swap
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).swap(amount0Out, amount1Out, address(this), data);
        // adding data triggers a flashloan
    }

    // in return of flashloan call, uniswap will return with this function
    // providing us the token borrow and the amount
    // we also have to repay the borrowed amt plus some fees
    function uniswapV2Call(
        address _sender,
        uint256 _amount0,
        uint256 _amount1,
        bytes calldata _data
    ) external override {
        // check msg.sender is the pair contract
        // take address of token0 n token1
        address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token0();
        address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token1();
        // call uniswapv2factory to getpair
        address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(UniswapV2Factory).getPair(token0, token1);
        require(msg.sender == pair, "!pair");
        // check sender holds the address who initiated the flash loans
        require(_sender == address(this), "!sender");

        (address tokenBorrow, uint amount, IUniswapV2Router02 _router) =
            // Decode flash swap triggered `_data`
            abi.decode(_data, (address, uint, IUniswapV2Router02));

        IERC20(tokenBorrow).approve(address(_router), amount);

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = tokenBorrow;
        path[1] = WETH;

        // Sell the token on Sushiswap with _address
        _router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amount,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );

        // 0.3% fees
        uint fee = ((amount * 3) / 997) + 1;
        uint amountToRepay = amount + fee;

        emit LogAddress("_sender", _sender);
        emit Log("_amount0", _amount0);
        emit Log("_amount1", _amount1);
        emit Log("fee", fee);
        emit Log("amountToRepay", amountToRepay);

        require(IERC20(tokenBorrow).balanceOf(address(this)) >= amountToRepay, "Not enough repay!");

        IERC20(tokenBorrow).transfer(pair, amountToRepay);
    }

    function calculateRepayAmount(uint _amount) public view returns (uint amountToRepay, uint fee) {
        fee = ((_amount * 3) / 997) + 1;
        amountToRepay = _amount + fee;
    }
}
```